# FluentValidation: assign error message to another variable outside validation logic

Tags: c#, .net, validation, fluent

I'd like to validate input **list of strings** by filtering it whether it correlates my conditions and I want to **assign** the error message for all invalid strings to **additional variable**, which can be accesable somewhere in the code.

I'm using **PreValidate** method to filter out all input strings, and I have **error message** for all invalid strings in a variable inside this method. All I need **to pass** this error message to another variable **outside validation** logic, so I'd like to know whether it's possible to do at all.

I set my logic inside **Prevalidate method**, where I'm filtering out Incorrect Names, according the logic of static CheckingNames method. It takes list of names in string format and returns **error message** for all invalid strings. In **out variable** it also returns **valid names**, which actually will be using later.

```
public class NameValidator : AbstractValidator<Order>
    {

  //Just simple rules for validate properties of Order Class

            RuleFor(x => x.From)
                .NotEqual(default(DateTime))
                .WithMessage("{PropertyName} parameter is mandatory");

            RuleFor(x => x.To)
                .NotEqual(default(DateTime))
                .WithMessage("{PropertyName} parameter is mandatory")
                .GreaterThan(x => x.From)
                .WithMessage("Invalid Time Range!")
                .LessThan(x => x.From.AddMonths(2))
                .WithMessage("Maximum selected time range must not exceed 2 months");


        }

protected override bool PreValidate(ValidationContext<Order> context, ValidationResult result)
        {
            var validAssets = new List<string>();

            var errors = Validation.CheckingNames(context.InstanceToValidate.Names, out validNames);
            context.InstanceToValidate.Names = validNames;

            return true;
        }
}
```

I want to assign the value of errors variable inside Prevalidate method to another variable outside validation logic.

Comment: If you have access to the NameValidator instance, just add variable and a getter function to the class. Assign the errors to the variable and get it through the function after validation is finished.

Comment: Sorry for late repply, but thanks! I used your simple notation and it worked like charm.